# JNI, Accessing SurfaceTexture using Native Code

Tags: android, android-ndk

I need to be able to execute native code ( algorithms ) on a video stream generated by the device camera, for that, I have considered OpenCV camera capture, Unfortunetly, at this time, it doesn't support Android 4.0.3 @ Samsung G2 which is my target device, as an alternative, I consider capture using the [Java Camera object](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html), and, using JNI, to ~Marshal~ the captured data to the native domain, this however, impose marshaling overhead ( coping the data ), to avoid that, I have considered rendering the captured image ( preview ) to a [GL Texture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html) ( using eg. [Camera.setPreviewTexture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setPreviewTexture%28android.graphics.SurfaceTexture%29) ), and, directly accessing the GL Texture @ the native domain, and thus, avoiding the un-needed coping.

**Is there a way to directly access the [TextureSurface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html) @ the native domain ?**

Any help will be appreciated.

Nadav At Sophin

Answer (score 1):

The VideoPlayback sample app released as part of Qualcomm's Vuforia augmented reality SDK achieves this I think. I've only just started going over the code myself these past few days and a lot of it's new to me so I'm not 100% sure.

https://ar.qualcomm.at/content/video-playback-sample-app-posted

If I'm right, the app plays a movie file through the Java domain's MediaPlayer class which is rendered to a SurfaceTexture which is then in turn accessed by the OpenGL ES code in the native domain to be rendered on the actual augmented reality display.